# Windows Phone: RemoveBackEntry after navigate failing

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I've got an intermediate "Loading" page for my game: I send them there and it has "Loading..." text that displays while the rather hefty game page loads up:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
            }
        });
}
```

Then when you hit the back button you go to the main page rather than back to the loading screen. There's no other logic on the page.

However I just got a store submission declined: apparently on the Samsung Focus and Odyssey the navigation entry for the loading page didn't get removed, and the user is sent back to the loading page when they hit the back button, rather than back to the main menu. I'm guessing RemoveBackEntry failed.

This looks like it should work, I can't reproduce the error and I don't have a Focus or Odyssey to work with. Does anybody know what might be going wrong?

Comment: The best here would be a Beta tester with such a phone as it's hard to say. Maybe somebody owns such a phone here a will help. Maybe for not leaving user with loading Page, you can put in OnLoad just Navigation with context=true, and then in GamePage after navigatioon remove back entry (depending on context = true). If crashes the user at least will be in GamePage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

with:

```
 while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
 {
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
 }
```

Comment: But I don't want to remove all back entries. Only one. Also, how would that help? Why didn't my previous code work?

Comment: Do you want to remove loading page only? I also didn't find the problem.

Comment: @ChrisShao It seems that the problem concenrs specific Phone models Samsung Focus and Odyssey

Comment: @Romasz, Thanks for your comment.Maybe the problem is phone models.but i can't test it because i don't have the special device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that `NavigationService.Navigate` will perform the navigation **asynchronously**. So when you call `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()`, the current page might not yet be on the BackStack.

To fix that, call `RemoveBackEntry` in `OnNavigatedTo` of GamePage.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Unfortunate that it doesn't seem to work every time since I will need to check the back stack to make sure that the loading page is on the top before removing the back entry. Since OnNavigatedTo fires when you back into a page as well.