# Windows Phone 8 : Prevent a PhoneApplicationPage from being added to backstack

Tags: windows-phone-8, back-stack

I have a phone page which navigates to another. Is there a way to prevent the fist page from getting into the backstack when navigating to the second?

I'd rather not remove the first page from the backstack in the code for the second page.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. You want to do that to avoid returning to this (the first) page from the second one using the back button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious way kind of works:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(...));
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

But it may fail - see submision problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845184/windows-phone-removebackentry-after-navigate-failing).

If you were to remove the BackStack Entry on the second page (and thus disperse the knowledge of the first page behaviour in context of navigation), you would to that in `OnNavigatedTo`, which occurs after the navigation is completed and the entry is placed on the `BackStack`. PhoneApplicationPage similarly has `OnNavigatedFrom` method, which is also called after the navigation is completed (`OnNavigatingFrom` is called before navigation and allows cancelling). So first page could remove itself in the following way:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

However, this method is incomplete, as `OnNavigatedFrom` is called not only after a succesfull `Navigate`, but also after pressing any of the three device buttons or showing a `Launcher` or `Chooser` (from `Microsoft.Phone.Task`). In those cases current page will not be placed on the `BackStack` (I guess that's why the `BackStack` corrections are applied usually on other Pages). So to fix the above method you could check if the last entry is what it should be:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();
    if (entry != null && entry.Source.OriginalString.Contains(...))
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, nice, including Launchers/Choosers and other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement when implementing a login page. Upon navigation to the authenticated area of the app, I want to remove the login page from the backstack.

To do this, I simply pop the stack after the call for the navigation out of the login view.

```
NavigationService.Navigate("/Page2.xaml");
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

This doesn't require code in your Page2.xaml.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way. Why won't you remove it if you don't want it to be there?

Comment: Imagine a page implementing a simple selection mechanism like a full screen Combobox. After selection an option you don't want to go back there using the back button.

Comment: Actually, to do that you navigate _forward_ to the picker page and go _back_ after picking. All pickers are built that way.